# Using Selenium to Scrape Infinite Scroll problem

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, infinite-scroll

I'm not able to scrape the title of each handbag, price, and color. The website is: https://www.coach.com/shop/women-handbags

I have already tried different scrapers, as well as placing the scraping information in different parts of the while loop.

The code provided is after the while loop scrolls the entire page and then goes back to the very top.

```
products = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[8]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div')

for product in products:
    bag_dict = {}
    try:
        name = product.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text
        price = thing.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="price-sales"]').text
        bag_dict['name'] = name
        bag_dict['price'] = price
    except:
        continue
print(bag_dict)
```

I get an empty dictionary or an error message that says bag_dict is not found.

Comment: WE’RE SORRY
Our site is temporarily offline for maintenance.
Thank you for your patience and check back soon.

Comment: That xpath to find products is only going to find 1 element isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Found a request made by the site that loads the handbags in sets of 24, this code will loop through all the sets and then store the price and name of each handbag in a dataframe. Selenium is not necessary to accomplish this, I used requests and beautifulsoup.

## Code

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

handbags = pd.DataFrame()
for next_set in range(0, 481, 24):
    payload = f'start={next_set}&format=page-element'
    r = requests.get('https://www.coach.com/shop/women-handbags', params = payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    names = [name.meta['content'] for name in soup.find_all(class_="product-name")]
    prices = [price.find('span', {'data-sales-price': re.compile(r'\d+\.\d+')})['data-sales-price'] for price in soup.find_all(class_="product-price")]

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Names': names, 'Prices': prices})
    handbags = handbags.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
    print("Appended next set")


print(handbags)
```

## Output

```
                                                 Names  Prices
0                            TROUPE TOTE IN COLORBLOCK   695.0
1      TROUPE TOTE IN COLORBLOCK WITH SNAKESKIN DETAIL   750.0
2                                          TROUPE TOTE   695.0
3                 TROUPE TOTE WITH KAFFE FASSETT PRINT   795.0
4    TROUPE TOTE IN SIGNATURE CANVAS WITH PATCHWORK...   895.0
5    TROUPE TOTE IN SIGNATURE CANVAS WITH KAFFE FAS...   795.0
6                      TROUPE TOTE IN SIGNATURE CANVAS   695.0
7                TROUPE CARRYALL WITH CROCODILE DETAIL  1100.0
8                                      TROUPE CARRYALL   595.0
9                  TROUPE CARRYALL IN SIGNATURE CANVAS   595.0
10   TROUPE CARRYALL 35 IN COLORBLOCK WITH SNAKESKI...   850.0
11   TROUPE CARRYALL 35 IN SIGNATURE CANVAS WITH KA...   995.0
12        TROUPE SHOULDER BAG WITH KAFFE FASSETT PRINT   550.0
13           TROUPE CROSSBODY WITH KAFFE FASSETT PRINT   595.0
14                                    TROUPE CROSSBODY   495.0
15                TROUPE CROSSBODY IN SIGNATURE CANVAS   495.0
16            TABBY TOP HANDLE IN COLORBLOCK SNAKESKIN   695.0
17                      TABBY TOP HANDLE IN COLORBLOCK   550.0
18                      TABBY TOP HANDLE IN COLORBLOCK   550.0
19                                    TABBY TOP HANDLE   550.0
20   TABBY TOP HANDLE IN SIGNATURE CANVAS WITH KAFF...   650.0
21   TABBY SHOULDER BAG 26 IN SIGNATURE CANVAS WITH...   450.0
22                  TABBY SHOULDER BAG 26 IN SNAKESKIN   650.0
23   TABBY SHOULDER BAG 26 IN COLORBLOCK WITH SNAKE...   450.0
24                 TABBY SHOULDER BAG 26 IN COLORBLOCK   350.0
25   TABBY SHOULDER BAG 26 IN COLORBLOCK WITH SNAKE...   450.0
26                               TABBY SHOULDER BAG 26   350.0
27                               TABBY SHOULDER BAG 26   350.0
28         TABBY SHOULDER BAG WITH KAFFE FASSETT PRINT   550.0
29                     TABBY SHOULDER BAG IN SNAKESKIN   595.0
..                                                 ...     ...
439                                  DINKY CHAIN STRAP    35.0
440                                      NOVELTY STRAP    95.0
441                                      NOVELTY STRAP    50.0
442                          STRAP IN SIGNATURE CANVAS    95.0
443                                 STRAP IN SNAKESKIN   150.0
444                                   STRAP WITH CHAIN   150.0
445     STRAP WITH WAVE PATCHWORK AND SNAKESKIN DETAIL   150.0
446                                   CASSIE CROSSBODY   350.0
447            NOVELTY STRAP WITH TEA ROSE AND TOOLING   150.0
448                              CENTRAL TOTE WITH ZIP   295.0
449                                   DREAMER WRISTLET   175.0
450                     DREAMER WRISTLET IN COLORBLOCK   175.0
451               DREAMER WRISTLET IN SIGNATURE CANVAS   175.0
452             DREAMER WRISTLET WITH SNAKESKIN DETAIL   225.0
453                        RIVINGTON CONVERTIBLE POUCH   250.0
454    RIVINGTON CONVERTIBLE POUCH IN SIGNATURE CANVAS   250.0
455                                        ROGUE POUCH   325.0
456                                        ROGUE POUCH   325.0
457                                      CHARLIE POUCH   175.0
458       CHARLIE POUCH IN COLORBLOCK SIGNATURE CANVAS   175.0
459            CHARLIE POUCH WITH MEADOW PRAIRIE PRINT   195.0
460                CHARLIE POUCH WITH SCATTERED RIVETS   195.0
461       CHARLIE POUCH WITH SIGNATURE CANVAS BLOCKING   175.0
462                                LARGE CHARLIE POUCH   225.0
463         LARGE CHARLIE POUCH WITH PATCHWORK STRIPES   275.0
464          LARGE CHARLIE POUCH WITH SCATTERED RIVETS   275.0
465  LARGE WRISTLET 30 IN SIGNATURE CANVAS WITH STA...   195.0
466           LARGE WRISTLET 30 WITH REXY AND CARRIAGE   195.0
467                                    KISSLOCK CLUTCH   225.0
468                      KISSLOCK CLUTCH IN COLORBLOCK   225.0

[469 rows x 2 columns]
```